# Bootstrap v4 media query not working in Chrome dev tools device tool

Tags: bootstrap-4, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using a div with the Bootstrap classes: "d-none d-md-block", so I expect the div to be hidden for small devices. However, when I'm in chrome dev tools and using the device toolbar it seems to ignore the dimensions.. With Laravel < v4 I never had problems with. So:

[image]

Does not care about the dimensions. It uses the media query min-width: 768px, however the dimensions are much smaller..

[image]

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Does your mobile simulation have a multiplication factor? 375 may actually be 3x that.

Comment: Yes, the iPhone X has a native resolution of 1125px, probably with a display density of 3:1.

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix by adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the header